# Find value V which concatenated to a String after using SHA256 algorithm has x number of zeros at the final hash based in an input

Tags: java, sha

```
private static String datosTransaccion;
private static int numeroCeros;
private static String cadenaV;
private static int numIntentos;

public SHA256(String datosTransaccion, int numeroCeros) {
    this.datosTransaccion = datosTransaccion;
    this.numeroCeros = numeroCeros;
}

public String algoritmo() {
    System.out.println("Empezando el algoritmo de encriptacion");
    MessageDigest digest;
    String encriptado = "Error";
    try {
        digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        Boolean centinela = false;

        while (centinela == false) {
            numIntentos += 1;
            System.out.println("intento numero:" + numIntentos);
            cadenaV = generadorCadenaV();
            System.out.println(cadenaV);
            String cadena = datosTransaccion + cadenaV;
            System.out.println(cadena);
            final byte[] hashbytes = digest.digest(cadena.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            int cuenta = 0;
            int numCeros = numeroCeros / 4;
            encriptado = bytesToHex(hashbytes);
            System.out.println(encriptado);
            for (int i = 0; i < numCeros - 1; i++) {
                if (encriptado.substring(i, i + 1).equals("0")) {
                    cuenta += 1;
                    System.out.println(cuenta);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(numeroCeros);
            if (cuenta * 4 == numeroCeros) {
                centinela = true;
            }
        }

        return encriptado;

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return encriptado;
}

private static String bytesToHex(byte[] hash) {
    StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder(2 * hash.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < hash.length; i++) {
        String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xff & hash[i]);
        if (hex.length() == 1) {
            hexString.append('0');
        }
        hexString.append(hex);
    }
    return hexString.toString();
}

public String generadorCadenaV() {
    int leftLimit = 97; // letra 'a'
    int rightLimit = 122; // letra 'z'
    Random rand = new Random();
    int targetStringLength = rand.nextInt(7) + 1; // longitud entre 1-7
    Random random = new Random();

    String cadenaV = random.ints(leftLimit, rightLimit + 1).limit(targetStringLength)
            .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append).toString();

    return cadenaV;
}

public String darCadenaV() {
    return cadenaV;
}

public int darIntentos() {
    return numIntentos;
}
```

The main problem here is that I need to generate the V string of size 1-7 with values a-z so that I get the number of 0's at the start of the string that I desire. And My program should return that but it's too long and it never ends. I need a Linear Solution to this. An example of a successful output is:

[image]

Comment: This is not a problem that you're going to be able to solve fast.  SHA is _specifically designed_ so that solving this fast is extremely difficult.

Comment: Yep, but still my professor says that maximum it needs to take 15 mins :(

Comment: Your professor asked you to personally break Bitcoin?

Comment: Problematic:
Bitcoin records transactions in blocks of a defined size and chains the cryptographic hash codes of said
blocks to ensure data integrity. Additionally, bitcoin includes a procedure known as
"mined"; This procedure must be executed for each block and is responsible for looking for a value (v) that concatenated with
transactions that are already in the block, allows generating a cryptographic hash code (ch) that meets a condition
specific; *This is literally the  first paragraph of the project guide for the class translated from spanish to english in Google*

Comment: Your task is to write a Java program that:
• It receives as input data: (i) a cryptographic hash code generation algorithm, (ii) a string that
represents the data of a transaction and (iii) an integer that indicates the searched number of zeros.
• Scans a search space, looking for a value v such that the cryptographic hash code of the string
input concatenated with v has the desired number of zeros at its beginning.

Comment: You cannot use the break, or continue statements. We are going to contribute to the break, continue, goto vs.
structured programming.
• Do not use special libraries, only standard java libraries (java.security). If you have any questions about a
specific bookstore check with teachers.
• The program must report the input string used, the value v that allows fulfilling the defined condition and the
time it took to do the search.